# Cordova navigator.notification is null

Tags: android, cordova, notifications

I have installed the dialogs plugin via

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs
```

Then I tried to run this from the chrome debug console

```
navigator.notification.alert(
    'You are the winner!',  // message
    function(){},         // callback
    'Game Over',            // title
    'Done'                  // buttonName
);
```

and I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'alert' of undefined
```

I ran `console.log(navigator)` and it is there but missing the notification. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? I'm targeting android for this build.

Here is my cordova config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add

`<script src="cordova.js"></script>`

in the head of my index.html file